# Get list of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I want to list all running threads but not by using the `List<>` class. I want to dynamically  observe running threads. How can I do that?

Comment: will `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` suffice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enumerate all managed threads in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466799/how-can-i-enumerate-all-managed-threads-in-c)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessThreadCollection currentThreads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;

foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)    
{
   // Do whatever you need
}
```

Answer (score 73):

### Method 1: Get OS Threads

This gets the list of OS threads:

```
ProcessThreadCollection currentThreads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;

foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)
{
}
```

### Method 2: Get Managed Threads

Managed threads sit on top of OS threads. The IDs are different, and in theory, more than one Managed Thread may sit on top of a single OS thread (although I havn't actually observed this).

It turns out that getting managed threads is trickier than it really should be.

#### Method 2.1: Simplest code to get Managed Threads

1. Check out [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd).
2. Install NuGet package [CLR Memory Diagnostics (ClrMD)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime).

You can then use said NuGet package to attach to your own process, and read the managed threads out:

```
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime;

using (DataTarget target = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, 5000, AttachFlag.Passive))
{
    ClrRuntime runtime = target.ClrVersions.First().CreateRuntime();
    foreach (ClrThread thread in runtime.Threads)
    {
    }
}
```

#### Method 2.2: Example of how to search through managed threads by stack trace

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to search through the list of threads by the thread name.

However, all is not lost: here is an example of how to create a managed thread, then find it by searching through the stack frames for a match on the namespace, then print out its properties:

```
namespace MyTest
{
    int managedThreadId = 0;
    var task = Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            // Unfortunately, cant see "Testing" anywhere in result returned
            // from NuGet package ClrMD ...
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Testing";
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
        });


    // ... so we look for our thread by the first word in this namespace.
    string startOfThisNamespace = this.GetType().Namespace.ToString().Split('.')[0]; // Is "MyTest".
    using (DataTarget target = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, 5000, AttachFlag.Passive))
    {
        ClrRuntime runtime = target.ClrVersions.First().CreateRuntime();

        foreach (ClrThread thread in runtime.Threads)
        {
            IList<ClrStackFrame> stackFrames = thread.StackTrace;

            List<ClrStackFrame> stackframesRelatedToUs = stackFrames
                .Where(o => o.Method != null && o.Method.ToString().StartsWith(startOfThisNamespace)).ToList();

            if (stackframesRelatedToUs.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.Write("ManagedThreadId: {0}, OSThreadId: {1}, Thread: IsAlive: {2}, IsBackground: {3}:\n", thread.ManagedThreadId, thread.OSThreadId, thread.IsAlive, thread.IsBackground);
                Console.Write("- Stack frames related namespace '{0}':\n", startOfThisNamespace);
                foreach (var s in stackframesRelatedToUs)
                {
                    Console.Write("  - StackFrame: {0}\n", s.Method.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also find the correct match by saving `ManagedThreadId` within the thread that you create, then looking for this same ID in `runtime.Threads`.

### Testing

Tested with all combinations of:

- Visual Studio 2015 SP1
- .NET 4.5
- .NET 4.6.0
- .NET 4.6.1
- C# 5.0
- C# 6.0

### References

See [ClrMd throws exception when creating runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633541/clrmd-throws-exception-when-creating-runtime/31745689#31745689).

Comment: The best answer I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`. Do I really need to install extra software just in order to see the threads in my application?

Comment: @Dominique Did you install the NuGet package that was mentioned in the answer? If you want to query managed threads, then this is required. Are you are aware of a dependency-free method to achieve this?

Comment: This crashes my application on Linux. I guess because it has a huge heap. I am surprised that this is such an expensive and contrived operation. In the JVM world it is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Updated code to get a snapshot of all stack traces that uses the answer from @Contango as a base. You'll still need to install NuGet package [CLR Memory Diagnostics (ClrMD)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime). This snippet also includes extra code to get the thread names, but this isn't required if you just want the stack traces.

edit: As pointed out by @abulhol in the commends, the fields `m_ManagedThreadId` and `m_Name` may be `_managedThreadId` and `_name` depending on your C# version.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime;

namespace CSharpUtils.wrc.utils.debugging
{
    public static class StackTraceAnalysis
    {
        public static string GetAllStackTraces()
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            
            using (var target = DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id))
            {
                var runtime = target.ClrVersions.First().CreateRuntime();

                // We can't get the thread name from the ClrThead objects, so we'll look for
                // Thread instances on the heap and get the names from those.    
                var threadNameLookup = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                foreach (var obj in runtime.Heap.EnumerateObjects())
                {
                    if (!(obj.Type is null) && obj.Type.Name == "System.Threading.Thread")
                    {
                        var threadId = obj.ReadField<int>("m_ManagedThreadId");
                        var threadName = obj.ReadStringField("m_Name");
                        threadNameLookup[threadId] = threadName;
                    }
                }

                foreach (var thread in runtime.Threads)
                {
                    threadNameLookup.TryGetValue(thread.ManagedThreadId, out string threadName);
                    result.AppendLine(
                        $"ManagedThreadId: {thread.ManagedThreadId}, Name: {threadName}, OSThreadId: {thread.OSThreadId}, Thread: IsAlive: {thread.IsAlive}, IsBackground: {thread.IsBackground}");
                    foreach (var clrStackFrame in thread.EnumerateStackTrace())
                        result.AppendLine($"{clrStackFrame.Method}");
                }
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this code, it basically works. But I cannot get the thread IDs, I get this exception in the first `foreach` loop: `System.ArgumentException: Type 'System.Threading.Thread' does not contain a field named 'm_ManagedThreadId' at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.ClrObject.ReadField[T](String fieldName)`

Comment: @abulhol My only thought is the field might have been renamed in a different version of C#. Try going through all the fields in obj.Type.Fields and see if there's anything else that looks like it might be correct.

Comment: I have found out, the field names changed to `_managedThreadId` and `_name`, see https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Thread.CoreCLR.cs,07a0689f2914aaaa. This is with .NET 6.0 btw.