# Finding running threads in a from

Tags: c#

My program has many running threads with each a unique name give to it. All the threads are same but the names for them are different. I know each of the threads name. I want to find the thread with its name and abort it. 
When finding textboxes I use,

```
TextBox mytextbox = ((TextBox) this.Controls.Find("logtextbox",true)[0]);
```

but i can't the use the same way for threads.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315862/get-list-of-threads

Comment: Aborting threads is almost always the wrong thing to do. You might consider a way to signal a thread to cleanly come to a stop.