# Find offending thread causing CannotUnloadAppDomainException

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

In my C# .Net 4.0 project, I use AppDomains to load plugin assemblies, ask them to do work, and then unload the AppDomain so I don't have to keep the assemblies in the main process.

For one particular plugin, I get a `CannotUnloadAppDomainException` when I call `AppDomain.Unload()`. I have found that this is most likely because the plugin has started a background thread which is either stuck or taking a long time (~10 seconds) in a `catch` or `finally` block. Unfortunately, I have no idea where the thread is.

This only happens on a customer's machine so I can't use my debugger to help.  I can, however, give them a patch to write more information to a logfile if I can find something more helpful to write out.

I have the source code for the plugin assembly and I have been trying to do some static analysis and running some tests, but it is quite large and I have had no luck finding a place where it is getting stuck in a `catch` or `finally`.

My questions:

1. Is there any way where upon getting a `CannotUnloadAppDomainException` that I can get a list of threads that are running with their callstacks in the child AppDomain?
2. Other than `catch` and `finally` blocks, are there other code sections that can throw this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime library mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315862/get-list-of-threads) (which is a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime)) I was able to list all threads still running and their callstacks when the child AppDomain's function was about to return. I did have to temporarily upgrade my app to .NET 4.5 to run with the library, but the source for the library is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd) so it may be possible to build this library with < .Net 4.5

It turns out that it was a bug in a third party library that handles our database connection that left a couple locked up threads when the database was using SSL on the local machine.

Comment: we had a similar issue on a win 2012 server running a windows service - strangely enough when the same code was run on win 10 (even as a service) the `CannotUnloadAppDomainException` did not surface. we had a non background thread that was left in the app domain; cleaning exiting the thread solved our problem

Answer (score 1):

Have the client run [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) to get a ETW trace of the program when it happens, it should let you get some more detailed information on what is running during the exact moment the exception happens. Here is [a set of video tutorials from Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial) that show you how to use it.