# In asp.net how can i get list of all running threads (Managed)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2015

In asp.net with c# how can i get list of all running threads.
I put a button in asp.net form & when i click on it a thread will be run like this :

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string thread_name = "trd_" + rnd.Next(99000, 10000000).ToString();
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Thread_Method(thread_name));
thread.Name = thread_name;
thread.Start();
```

Now in another button click how can i gather all of those running thread  names?

Comment: Add the name to a global list when you create the thread?

Comment: We can add them to a global, SURE. But there should be a way to track managed threads without adding them to a global variable by ourselves!.

Comment: Creating a thread in ASP.NET is a bad idea

Comment: Working on it, Very beautiful. -:)

Comment: Did you tried something from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315862/get-list-of-threads

Comment: Yep, I think it's different. My managed threads ids are like this : 21,22,23,... But current process threads ids are like this : 4567,3245,...

Comment: This link does not support .Net 3.5 > https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime